# load data from csv with encoding utf-16le

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark version 3.1.2, and I need to load data from a csv with encoding utf-16le.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("header", true)
    .option("encoding", "utf-16le")
    .load(file_path)
df.show(4)
```

It seems spark can only read the first line normally:
[Starting from the second row, either garbled characters or null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1rTV.png)

however, python can read the data correct with code:

```
with open(file_path, encoding='utf-16le', mode='r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
```

print result like:
[python read correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAASz.png)

Comment: Give it a try by adding `option('encoding', 'UTF-16').option('multiline', 'true')`

Comment: great! works perfect.

Comment: @PengZhou Since your problem was solved by user `@Vikramsinh Shinde` you may want to mark his response (posted below) as an `Answer`. This will also help other reader recognize that there is a possible solution to the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add these options while creating Spark dataframe from CSV file source -

```
.option('encoding', 'UTF-16')
.option('multiline', 'true')
```